# How to split String List to sub String list in Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i use Selenium to get some Lecture information what i listen now 
and i stored it to `List<String> list`   as `String`
There is a list of lectures that I am currently listening to,
but each lecture has different information that contains the form of the lecture.
These are the two forms below.

Lecture Number: 1, 
Categorization: Online,  
Lecture Name: 2. Preparation for learning algorithms 1,  
Learning status: full,  
Study time / class date: 30 minutes,  
Attendance information (within the period): TOTAL: 30 minutes 33 seconds  
web 30 minutes 33 seconds  
mobile 0 seconds, 
Attendance information (after the period): TOTAL: 0 seconds, 
web 0 seconds,  
mobile 0 seconds,

Lecture number: 1 
Categorization: Offline 
Lecture Name: Subject Introduction - What is Data?  
Learning Status: -  
Learning time/class date: 2022-03-02  
Attendance information (within the period) Attendance information (after the period): not processed 
To learn: a teaching plan

after store that into `List<String> list`  
and when i use this

```
    for(String text: list)
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

The results are as follows:

1, 
Online 
2. Preparation for learning algorithms 1, 
full 
30 minutes 
TOTAL 30 
minutes 33 seconds  
web 30 minutes 33 seconds  
mobile 0 seconds 
TOTAL: 0 seconds  
web 0 seconds 
mobile 0 seconds

1 
Offline 
Subject Introduction - What is Data?

-

2022-03-02 
not processed 
a teaching plan

How can i store two forms of lecture in different List? 
The goal is to put it into the database 
but before that i want to seperate into different List

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object Lecture, for example:

```java
class Lecture {
  private int number;
  private String categorization;
  // omitted
}
```

Then parse field by field.

Comment: Why i have to make object Lecture ? Rather Not splitting List to multiple list

Comment: What if Lecture has more than 2 forms, and you have to create more than 2 Lists?

Comment: As u can see i use selenium and get lecture information above that and store it to String List, and after that i want to split it to with each lecture information list.